# when do use extension move instruction in assembly language

Tags: assembly, memory, x86, cpu-registers, zero-extension

I saw `movw %dx (%eax)` on my textbook, and I'm wondering why use `movw` rather than `movswl` or `movzwl` here?

I think that there are 2 bytes in `%dx` and 4 bytes in `(%eax)` (for a 32-bit machine), so it needs an extension?

Comment: `(%eax)` has no implied size. This instruction writes 2 bytes. If you wanted to write 4, you could use extension. Note that neither `movsx` nor `movzx` allow for a memory destination.

Comment: A 32-bit x86 can never do a 64-bit (8-byte) store with scalar integer registers in one instruction, except with `cmpxchg8b`.  You'd need x86-64 to be able to `mov %rdx, (%rax)` (aka `movq`), or in 32-bit use `movsd %xmm0, (%eax)` to store the low half of a vector register.

Comment: @PeterCordes oh I'm sorry! I mean 4 bytes actually~ Thanks~

Comment: Ok, then see Jester's comment.  x86 doesn't have any instructions that extend a register *and* store it to memory.  If you want to store 4 bytes to memory at the address from EAX, `movswl %dx, %edx` / `mov %edx, (%eax)`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I see! Thanks your explanation~